# Trying to return a blank cell or data by combining VLOOKUP IFERROR & IFBLANK

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I am having a little difficulty trying to return a blank cell where there is no data in a report I'm creating.

My formula is halfway there, I have successfully used the `IFERROR` function to remove the `#N/A`s from my data, but the fields with nothing in are returning `0`s.

My formula is

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C5,'Scheduler + Comments'!B:D,3,FALSE)," ")
```

Probably quite a simple answer to this but I'm spending way too long on this issue getting no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.
You can add an if function to check if the Vlookup has blank as result and in that case return a blank.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(C5,'Scheduler + Comments'!B:D,3,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP(C5,'Scheduler + Comments'!B:D,3,FALSE)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, your formula is correct but i can suggest some improvements.

This may helps

- Fix the range of C5 & B:D
- Remove the space between `" "`

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($C$5,'Scheduler + Comments'!$B:$D,3,FALSE),"")`

When i use the formula i get a blank cell as you wish.

Comment: Thanks, but this formula would still return a 0 where there was no data in the field the VLOOKUP was returning. The answer from Pierre fixed that issue.